# how to add event in google calendar? i am using Oauth for authorization and i am only getting the list of event

Tags: android, oauth, google-api

**how to add event in google calendar?i am using Oauth for authorization and i am only getting the list of event**

Answer (score 0):

Read the [Google Calendar API documents](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#CreatingEvents). They go over how to create events (one time or recurring), how to update events and how to delete events in addition to the retrieval.

Comment: thnx for answering but can u know me how to add xml in message body part in HTTP Post? .....Thnx

Comment: You create the HTTP Post request with the URL and adding in the OAuth header. Then you attach the XML to the message body. Depending on which language you are using, you should be able to find examples of this.

Comment: i don't know how to attach XML in the message body..so can you give me a example?

Comment: Export the XML to a string and then here's [a page](http://www.websitetoolbox.com/tool/support/117) that shows you how to do HTTP Post in various languages.